# Performing MongoDB's cursor.forEach() in ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I've just started experimenting with Ruby's Sinatra a couple of days ago, I'm trying to query a MongoDB, the [`find_one()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) method works very well, but when trying to get more than one document (i.e when using [`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/)) a cursor is returned, I'm used to using the [`cursor.forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach) method to iterate through all the returned documents, but as I am new to ruby, I am having a hard time figuring it out.

Would be great if you can point me in the right direction, also if you know of a Mongo/Ruby command dictionary or cheat sheet, I would really appreciate it.

Some code to help with the matter:

```
#The following code is intentionally formatted the way it is, (i.e the case 
#insensitive, the way I'm calling the database), all that is irrelevant, 
#but there to show you what I'm doing; I might be screwing up somewhere.

#works fine, returns JSON of required document
settings.mongo_db['col'].find_one({"key" => /#{value}/i}).to_json

#returns cursor, need to iterate
settings.mongo_db['col'].find({"key" => /#{value}/i}).to_json
```

Your replies/thoughts are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well generally in ruby in order to iterate you just use `.each` but since you just want to return your cursor results as JSON just turn the statement around

```
JSON.generate( settings.mongo_db['col'].find({"key" => /#{value}/i}).to_a )
```

So that should serialize as an array of documents.

Also see other methods in the [JSON package](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Comment: That's awesome! I never knew you could cast a cursor to an array!
Cheers mate :)

Comment: @MrHaze Apologies. Cut and paste gets me again, missed the `.to_a` method.

Comment: no worries, you've been much help, thanks!
I really had no idea you could manipulate a mongo cursor like that. (a bit new to mongo & ruby, they're awesome though).